# symfony kernel interface in custom bundle

Tags: symfony

I'm working with symfony4. I follow [this tutorial](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-bundle/bundle-directory) to create a custom bundle. Everything work fine.
From now I want to use the KernelInterface in my bundle. How can I add some services (like kernel) in my bundle?

I tried to add kernel in my bundle services.yml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services
    http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
<services>
    <service id="lilworks.youtubedl" class="Lilworks\YoutubeDlBundle\LilworksYoutubeDl" public="true">
        <argument type="service" id="kernel" />
    </service>
    <service id="Lilworks\YoutubeDlBundle\LilworksYoutubeDl" alias="lilworks.youtubedl" public="true"/>
</services>
```

```
<?php
namespace Lilworks\YoutubeDlBundle;


use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class LilworksYoutubeDl
{
  private $foo;
  private $bar;
  private $kernel;

public function __construct($foo,$bar,KernelInterface $kernelInterface)
{
    $this->foo = $foo;
    $this->bar = $bar;
    $this->kernel = $kernelInterface;

}

}
```

Comment: So don't leave us hanging: what happened?  Errors about $foo and $bar?  Absolutely nothing?  Some other error?  For bundles, services are manually configured so you are on the right track.  And off-topic but it's very unlikely you actually need access to the kernel.

Comment: What would you need the kernel for ? And how does XML go into the `services.yml` ?

Answer (score 1):

So I had to set my config parameter to 1 and 2 and leave 0 for the wanted service

```
class LilworksYoutubeDlExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {

        $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.xml');

        $configuration = $this->getConfiguration($configs, $container);
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $definition = $container->getDefinition('lilworks.youtubedl');

        $definition->setArgument(1, $config['foo']);
        $definition->setArgument(2, $config['bar']);

    }
    public function getAlias()
    {

        return 'lilworks_youtubedl';
    }
}
```

In my services.yml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services
        http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="lilworks.youtubedl" class="Lilworks\YoutubeDlBundle\LilworksYoutubeDl" public="true">
            <argument type="service" id="kernel" />
        </service>
        <service id="Lilworks\YoutubeDlBundle\LilworksYoutubeDl" alias="lilworks.youtubedl" public="true"/>
    </services>
</container>
```

And in the constructor of the bundle

```
class LilworksYoutubeDl
{
    private $foo;
    private $bar;
    private $kernel;

    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernelInterface,$foo,$bar)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
        $this->bar = $bar;
        $this->kernel = $kernelInterface;

    }
```